# Are functions in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ bounded when $p> N$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set with $C^1$ boundary (I'll call this kind of sets **regular domains**). I know that given $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ the following inequality (Gagliardo-Nirerberg-Sobolev) holds for any $r<N$ (and also for $r=N=1$):

$$||u||_{L^{r^*}(\Omega)}\leq C ||u||_{W^{1,r}(\Omega)}, \ \ \ \ r^*:=\frac{Nr}{N-r}.$$

This implies pretty easily that if $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $p\geq N$ then $u\in L^q(\Omega)$ for any $q\in [1,\infty)$.

What about $q=\infty$?

If $p=N\neq 1$ I know that a valid counterexample is $\log(\log(1+1/|x|))$.

If $p=N=1$ then $W^{1,1}(a,b)=AC(a,b)$ (absolutely continous functions) so no counterexample is possible.

If $p>N$ then I don't know if a counterexample exists and I need some help.

Comment: By Morrey-Sobolev inequalities, the function is Holder continuous

Comment: Adams, Sobolev Spaces 4.12 Theorem is where you can find all the embeddings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ into $C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)$ for $p> N$ and some $\alpha\in(0,1)$ (This is Morrey's inequality). Therefore, we get that for every $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, there is a bounded (Because hölder-continuous on bounded set) representation which is a.e. equal to $u$.